# Can I use Prioritized Learning when the transition probabilities are given?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, state-spaces, prioritized-sweeping

Can I use Prioritized Learning when the transition probabilities are given?

Also, as I can understand, Prioritized Sweeping is suitable when a state space is large. Can I use it when the state space is small (e.g. 10 states)?